# How to put the hover image above the original image

Tags: css, html

So i made a upvote/downvote button, i want the image to change when someone hover on it. Check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/g6Lhurae/30/)
If you look closely, the image is changing when you over but it is behind the original image. How to fix it?

HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons">
<input type="image" class="buttonup" id="plus" style="vertical-align:middle" src="http://i.imgur.com/jWPUjR9.png" /> <span id="count">1453</span>
  <input type="image" class="buttondw" id="minus" style="vertical-align:middle" src="http://i.imgur.com/Vu6tuf9.png" />

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#buttons{margin-left: 35%; margin-right:35%;}
.buttonup {
 padding: 0px;
 width: 50px;
 cursor: pointer;
 margin-right: 0px;
}

#count {
display: inline-block;
border-radius: 0px;
background-color: #33cc33;
border: none;
color: #ffffff;
text-align: center;
font-size: 18px;
padding: 7px;
width: 50px;
margin-top: 0px;

 }

.buttondw {
width: 50px;
cursor: pointer;
margin-left: 0px;
} 

.buttonup:hover {
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/SFjZ9FD.png")
 }
.buttondw:hover {
background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/aVAeO0F.png")
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use `<button>` + background image.

```css
#buttons {
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-right: 35%;
}
#count {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #33cc33;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.buttonup,
.buttondw {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.buttonup {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/jWPUjR9.png");
}
.buttondw {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/Vu6tuf9.png");
}
.buttonup:hover {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/SFjZ9FD.png");
}
.buttondw:hover {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/aVAeO0F.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <button class="buttonup" id="plus"></button> <span id="count">1453</span>
  <button class="buttondw" id="minus"></button>
</div>
```

If you need one button at the top and one at the bottom, you can wrap each group into a div.

```
<div id="buttons">
  <div>
    <button class="buttonup" id="plus"></button> <span id="count">1453</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="buttondw" id="minus"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
#buttons {
  margin-left: 35%;
  margin-right: 35%;
}
#count {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #33cc33;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.buttonup,
.buttondw {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.buttonup {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/jWPUjR9.png");
}
.buttondw {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/Vu6tuf9.png");
}
.buttonup:hover {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/SFjZ9FD.png");
}
.buttondw:hover {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/aVAeO0F.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="buttons">
  <div>
    <button class="buttonup" id="plus"></button> <span id="count">1453</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="buttondw" id="minus"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by setting the initial image with `background-image` instead of using `src`. Also, since there is no need to have input tags, you can just use `<div>`'s.

1. Make your input's divs.
2. Set the images as `backgroud-image`.
3. Add a height of 50px; to your `.buttonup` and `.buttondown`.

```js
var counter = 1453, // Try change this what ever you want
  votePlus = counter + 1,
  voteMinus = counter - 1;

function checkIfUserVoted() {
  return localStorage.getItem("voted");
}
if (!localStorage.getItem("voted")) {
  localStorage.setItem("voted", counter);
  $("#count").text(counter);
}
$(".buttonup").click(function() {
  var vote = checkIfUserVoted() != votePlus ? votePlus : counter;
  localStorage.setItem("voted", vote);
  $(this).next().text(vote);
});
$(".buttondw").on('click', function () {
  var vote = checkIfUserVoted() != voteMinus ? voteMinus : counter;
  localStorage.setItem("voted", vote);
  $(this).prev().text(vote);
});
```

```css
#buttons{margin-left: 35%; margin-right:35%;}
.buttonup {
  padding: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 0px;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/jWPUjR9.png');
}

#count {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0px;
  background-color: #33cc33;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 50px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  
}

.buttondw {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 0px;
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/Vu6tuf9.png');
}

.buttonup:hover {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/SFjZ9FD.png")
}
.buttondw:hover {
  background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/aVAeO0F.png")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="buttons">
<div type="image" class="buttonup" id="plus" style="vertical-align:middle"></div> <span id="count">1453</span>
<div type="image" class="buttondw" id="minus" style="vertical-align:middle"></div>
      
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're trying to set the background-image of an img element. That means aside from displaying the original image, it will also set the background to the hover image.

You can either make the original button have a background image, or use javascript to change the source of the `<img>`.

Try this code: https://fiddle.jshell.net/8gxhokL3/

Comment: Can you show me the CSS and HTML by editing my fiddle?

Comment: You only have to set background-image on the css buttons style, the url of background-image is the same of src elements attribute

Comment: Alright I edited your code to use `<a>`s with background images instead. https://fiddle.jshell.net/8gxhokL3/